# Rails association method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application i've applied a relationship between two table: Article and Category with a relation has_and_belongs_to_many.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I'm following this tutorial for implement a Has_many system with the checkboxes ([Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast))

i've write this part:

```
<% for category in Category.all%>
      <div>
        <%= check_box_tag "article[category_ids][]", category.id, @article.categories.include?(category) %>
        <%= category.name %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

but i've got this error :

> Mysql2::Error: Table 'CMS_development.articles_categories' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `articles_categories`

Where am i wrong?

**EDIT ADDING THE MIGRATION AND THE SCHEMA**

MIGRATION:

```
   class AddCategoryToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_reference :articles, :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
      end
    end
```

SCHEMA:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151001153131) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "published"
    t.boolean  "on_evidance"
    t.boolean  "foreground"
    t.string   "title",       limit: 255
    t.string   "subtitle",    limit: 255
    t.datetime "date"
    t.text     "body",        limit: 65535
    t.text     "small_body",  limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.integer  "category_id", limit: 4
  end

  add_index "articles", ["category_id"], name: "index_articles_on_category_id", using: :btree

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",        limit: 255
    t.text     "description", limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "articles", "categories"
end
```

Comment: A quick look at the asciicast shows no signs of migrations. Did you create and run them before trying this?

Comment: Are you sure you followed the Rails guidelines? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: yes i'm sure to had followed all the rails guidelines. i add the migration file and the schema.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You don't have the join table `articles_categories`
2. You're not referencing the `categories` correctly

---

Firstly, to use a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association, you need to invoke the appropriate *join table*:

[image]

Your schema shows, quite clearly, that you *don't* have this. As stated in other answers, you need to create a schema as follows:

```
   class CreateArticlesCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
          create_table :articles_categories, id: false  do |t|
             t.references :articles
             t.references :categories
          end
      end
    end
```

This will give you the join table which you'll be able to populate with your select box...

--

For your checkbox, you can do the following:

```
#app/views/articles/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :categories, Category.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

To populate this through the controller, you'd need to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @article = Article.new
   end
   def create
      @article = Article.new article_params
      @article.save
   end

   private

   def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :categories)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write and execute a migration for creating `articles_categories` table:

```
class CreateArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles_categories do |t|
      t.references :articles
      t.references :categories
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: but the  @article.categories.include?(category) should be working only with the specification of the relations between article and category because both have has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: @user3125036: You didn't create the middle table and it can not work without that.

Comment: so i should execute this command : 'rails g migration CreateArticleCategory articles:references categories:reference'  and then retry to execute the code?

Comment: @user3125036: After generating migration, you need to execute (`rake db:migrate` )it.

Comment: it doesn't work even in this way the error is the same